# Why is this question closed for off-topic, even though it appears to be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

While researching the very thing asked in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19391858/cannot-uninstall-visual-studio-2013, I found the question I just linked, which has been closed for off-topic, citing:

> "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User."

To me, this seems like a question that "directly involves tools used primarily for programming". In fact, [UnInstall Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10529116/uninstall-visual-studio-2010), which asks about the same question for an earlier version of VS, remains open.

I don't think I have the rep to vote to reopen this question, but to me it seems like this question shouldn't be closed.

Comment: @Deduplicator My main concern isn't that the reason doesn't fit. My main concern is that we're sending mixed signals. we have an open question about 2010, but a very similar question about 2013 is closed. How should someone who has a question about a programming tool that they cannot uninstall for some reason interpret this? Should they assume that their question is not allowed, since another question about it is locked? or should they assume that their question is allowed, since another question about is available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there some inconsistency? Yes there is.

Is this a problem?  I don't think so.

Yes, both questions are about uninstalling a specific piece of software that is commonly used by programmers, but there is one difference between the solutions to the 2 problems.

Based on the answer, for the 2010 version, there is a specific program that is unique to the software tool.  That seems to require a specific question and answer to help people find the solution.  But the top answers for the 2013 version, the solution is simple "try to uninstall by running the installer again".  I think someone who was trying to uninstall **any program** would try that solution first after the normal uninstall failed.  As such, it seems to fail the "do you research" expectation and the existing close reason would seem to fit since we would have expect the user had tried all of the normal uninstallation procedures before coming to Stack Overflow.